# JQuery validate throws error when creating a simple rule

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm creating a rule on a text input, but getting an error when the rule gets created. The error says

> Unhandled exception at line 147, column 4 in https://localhost:44368/Scripts/jquery.validate.js
>   0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'settings' of undefined or null reference"

which is coming from this line in the validate file

```
settings = $.data( element.form, "validator" ).settings;
```

where

```
$.data( element.form, "validator" )
```

is undefined. Why is this???

Here is the element

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" id="zipCodeText" type="text" placeholder="e. g. 94901" value="94102">
```

Here is the rule

```js
$('#zipCodeText').rules("add", {
  required: true,
  minlength: 5,
  maxlength: 5,
  messages: {
    required: "Required input",
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary"),
    maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, {0} characters are necessary")
  }
});
```

Comment: ok I solved it, I needed to add a role="form" attribute to the form tag! WTF!

Comment: ok I also noticed that the error is thrown if I don't validate the form first! is this correct?

Comment: Quote OP:  *"I needed to add a `role="form"` attribute to the form tag!"*  ~  [I don't think so.  Works fine without it.](http://jsfiddle.net/1rmLksw8/)

Answer (score 0):

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'settings' of undefined or null reference"

You **must** first *initialize* the plugin by calling the `.validate()` method on your form element.

```
$('#yourform').validate({ // <-- INITIALIZE the plugin on your form
    // any options, rules, or callbacks
});
```

---

> ok I also noticed that the error is thrown if I don't validate the form first! is this correct?

You don't "validate" the form first... you **"initialize"** it by calling the `.validate()` method.